# I need one proprieties of json file but my code pull out all of them

Tags: json

I have this problem I have to use a part of a json file because when the app calls an image it leans on the ID present in the json file

es.

```
<img (click) = "seeHeroDetails (hero)" mat-card-image src = "assets / images / heroes / {{hero.id}}. jpg">
```

But only that the page calls me all the json and not just the part that interests him and therefore does not call the image because he does not know which id to take, so how do I "cut" the rest of the json that I do not need?

this is the json

```
[
{
id: "1",
name: "Spiderman",
alter_ego: "Peter Parker",
likes: "106",
default: true,
},
{
id: "2",
name: "Superman",
alter_ego: "Clark Kent",
likes: "27",
default: true,
},
{
id: "3",
name: "Batman",
alter_ego: "Bruce Wayne",
likes: "98",
default: true,
},
{
id: "4",
name: "Wonder woman",
alter_ego: "Diana Prince",
likes: "78",
default: true,
},
{
id: "5",
name: "Iron man",
alter_ego: "Tony Stark",
likes: "65",
default: true,
},
```

I need this

```
[
{
id: "1",
name: "Spiderman",
alter_ego: "Peter Parker",
likes: "106",
default: true,
},
]
```

when i call the image.

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

I do not totally understand what you mean.

But if you have the *id*, then all you need to do is just run a loop on the json array and match the id field.

Here,

```js
const heroes = [{
        id: "1",
        name: "Spiderman",
        alter_ego: "Peter Parker",
        likes: "106",
        default: true,
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Superman",
        alter_ego: "Clark Kent",
        likes: "27",
        default: true,
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Batman",
        alter_ego: "Bruce Wayne",
        likes: "98",
        default: true,
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name: "Wonder woman",
        alter_ego: "Diana Prince",
        likes: "78",
        default: true,
    },
    {
        id: "5",
        name: "Iron man",
        alter_ego: "Tony Stark",
        likes: "65",
        default: true,
    }
];

function seeHeroDetails(id) {
    return heroes.find(hero => hero.id == id);
}

console.log(seeHeroDetails(1));
```